# How to dynamically modify my selection in multidimentional array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, grid

I built a sudoku grid creating a multidimentional array. 
One logic I try to implement is to check numbers around each of the nine centers.

```
var grid = [

  [1,4,2,8,0,6,7,9,5],
  [8,0,0,0,9,1,0,7,1],
  [4,9,0,2,5,2,0,0,0],
  [9,0,2,9,1,2,0,0,0],
  [0,5,8,8,5,3,9,0,0],
  [3,1,0,7,6,4,0,2,0],
  [2,3,0,1,5,8,7,9,4],
  [7,8,0,0,7,5,4,0,0],
  [6,0,7,4,3,7,0,0,9],
```

];

My centers from my sudoku grid are the following:

```
var gridCenters  = [grid[1][1],grid[1][4],grid[1][7],grid[4][1],grid[4][4],grid[4][7],grid[7][1],grid[7][4],grid[7][7]];
```

And the 9 numbers around each center (the center included) are the following:

```
var nineFromSquare = [grid[i][j],grid[i-1][j-1],grid[i-1][j],grid[i][j-1],grid[i+1][j+1],grid[i+1][j],grid[i+1][j],grid[i-1][j+1],grid[i+1][j-1]];
```

[Sudoku grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8ywq.jpg)

I try to create a for loop that takes each gridCenter and applies to its index a certain value to add additionnal logics for sudoku solving. Basically, I want to check if the numbers around the centers are numbers or empty.

Any tip? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't your `gridCenters` include `grid[1][1]`?

Comment: You are right Redu, just corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If a `0` on the boards designates empty than you may do as follows;

```js
function getBorder(center){
  var offsets = [[-1,-1],[0,-1],[1,-1],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[-1,1],[-1,0]];
  return offsets.map(c => [c[0] + center[0], c[1] + center[1]]);
}

function getNestedValue(o,...a){
  var val = o;
  for (var prop of a) val = typeof val === "object" &&
                                   val !== null     &&
                                   val[prop] !== void 0 ? val[prop]
                                                        : undefined;
  return val;
}

var grid = [[1,4,2,8,0,6,7,9,5],
            [8,0,0,0,9,1,0,7,1],
            [4,9,0,2,5,2,0,0,0],
            [9,0,2,9,1,2,0,0,0],
            [0,5,8,8,5,3,9,0,0],
            [3,1,0,7,6,4,0,2,0],
            [2,3,0,1,5,8,7,9,4],
            [7,8,0,0,7,5,4,0,0],
            [6,0,7,4,3,7,0,0,9],
           ],
centers  = [[1,1],[1,4],[1,7],[4,1],[4,4],[4,7],[7,1],[7,4],[7,7]];
  result = centers.map(c => getBorder(c).every(b => getNestedValue(grid,...b)));
console.log(result);
```

The `getBorder()` function returns us the 8 items that are surrounding the center item provided by the single argument of the function.
The `getNestedValue()` function will return you dynamically the items of an indefinitely nested properties of an object/array those are provided in an array in the correct order. In this case `[x,y]`

If you don't need a result for each center but one for all then you might convert the

```
result = centers.map(c => getBorder(c).every(b => getNestedValue(grid,...b)));
```

into;

```
result = centers.every(c => getBorder(c).every(b => getNestedValue(grid,...b)));
```